# PHP write into file "/n" not working

Tags: php

I actually tried all fixes i have seen on stack and other websites but its not working for me, this is my code

```
$date = date('l jS F Y h:i:s A');
$file = 'gLog.txt';
    if (!file_exists($file)) 
    {
        $myfile = fopen($file, "w");
        echo '<i class="green">'.$file.' created </i><br>';
    }
    $text = file_get_contents($file);
    $text .= "$date\n"; // also tried $text .= $date."\n";
    file_put_contents($file, $text);
```

And this is what i get

```
Tuesday 21st July 2015 08:07:03 AMTuesday 21st July 2015 08:07:16 AM
```

how do i get this

```
Tuesday 21st July 2015 08:07:03 AM
Tuesday 21st July 2015 08:07:16 AM
```

Comment: How are you looking at that file? Are you viewing it in a browser? In Windows notepad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`PHP_EOL;`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php)  FOR new line

```
 $text .= "$date".PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `PHP_EOL` Try this Code for UNIX systems `'\n'` works in windows systems `\r\n` works but `PHP_EOL` works in every systems

```
$date = date('l jS F Y h:i:s A');
$file = 'gLog.txt';
    if (!file_exists($file)) 
    {
        $myfile = fopen($file, "w");
        echo '<i class="green">'.$file.' created </i><br>';
    }
    $text = file_get_contents($file);
    $text .= "$date".PHP_EOL;
    file_put_contents($file, $text);
```